# On refresh the page previous table should be selected

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In my Wordpress site, there is a table on a page, when I change the pagination to 2 or 3 or any other the table updates, but when I refresh the page it brings me back to 1, is there any way so that keep me on my selected table.

Url: seoapproval.com/instant-approval-directory-submission-sites-list/

Comment: you can use some js to add #1, #2, #3 to the query string, then use some php to get it on reload and send the user to the right page. But please post what you have tried since now...

Answer (score 0):

Just found this plugin, fulfilling my all requirements :)
https://wordpress.org/plugins/sgr-nextpage-titles